# JavaScript prints nothing to the page

Tags: javascript, html

After running the HTML file the page appears blank.

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

What might be wrong?

Comment: You never call the function.

Comment: True, I added `myFunction();` to the end and it is printing now!

Comment: Make sure the html portion appears on the page before the JavaScript, unless you are  waiting for the Document Load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify what @tkausl said in the comment, you have defined a function, but have yet to execute (called) it. Try doing this:

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}
myFunction();
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: This is not guaranteed to work, since you operate on the DOM before it is loaded. Register an event handler to `DOMContentLoaded` instead.

Answer (score 1):

- A better approach, when the DOM is fully loaded using the event `DOMContentLoaded`.

```js
var person = {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 50,
  eyeColor: "blue"
};

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  myFunction();
});
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: I'm tempted to upvote this answer, but I am unsure why you include the wrong code (which is duplicated in many other answers) in the first place.

Comment: @phihag well, I just wanted to show the OP's approach vs a better approach.  Do you think this is not a good idea?

Comment: In my experience, many people tend to copy code in stackoverflow answers without much thought. So if you have incorrect code, there should be blatant red lettering and comments that it shouldn't be used. Your second example already shows the function call (as opposed to `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myFunction);`, which is the real answer here).

Comment: @phihag yes, you're right.  Many people tend to copy code.  Answer updated!

Answer (score -2):

You need to call the function somewhere in the js code.. Something like:

```
window.onload="myFunction()";
```

Or, make it a self executing function:

```
<script>
(function() {
    myFunction()
})();
</script>
```

Comment: `window.onload` means `DOMContentLoaded`?

Comment: I guess.. Never used it though

Comment: Assigning a string to `onload` won't work in modern browsers anymore. To boot, as @Bontano said, load is the incorrect event here. The second variant is even crazier: Even if calling the function would be correct (it's not, but may often work, depending on the timing), there is absolutely no reason to wrap it in a self-executing function instead of just calling it outright.

Comment: @phihag.. they were just suggestions for running a sample script.. Hence the reason for "something like" in the first statement. There was no reason for down-rating. The suggestions work perfectly fine for the question asked